# Is it possible to use a Bash script to process an input file 5 rows at a time?

Tags: bash

If an input file "input.txt" contains 10 rows of echo commands.  Is it possible to process 5 rows at a time?  Once a row completes its command run the next row in the file.

e.g.

```
$ cat input.txt
echo command 1
echo command 2
echo command 3
echo command 4 
echo command 5
echo command 6
echo command 7
echo command 8
echo command 9 
echo command 10
```

I realize these are simple commands, the ultimate idea is to run up to 5 rows of commands at a time and once each once completes successfully, a new command from the input file would start.

Comment: Since all the commands are being run in order, what difference does it make how you group them? Do you want to run all 5 commands in the group concurrently?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the idea of what I'm trying to convey, the commands aren't echo commands.  The input file contains information that is bing piped into a variable and then used to start automated process streams within Autosys.

Comment: I don't care what the commands are, my question is about what it means to do them in groups versus just executing them normally.

Comment: They could be run in succession instead of simultaneously, but can't succeed 5 at a time, and another part of the script is supposed to check the status of the jobs that the commands effect, some take longer than others.  This is completely over my head so I'm trying to understand each section one part at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
$ cat input.txt | parallel -j5
```

Comment: Beware of the *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Unless you are actually *concatenating* 2 files, `cat ...` is usually the wrong approach. `parallel -j5 <input.txt` will avoid spawning an additional subshell that pipe requires.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `cat input.txt` is useful as a placeholder in examples for an arbitrary program or script that's actually generating the data.

Comment: I'm still thinking though that one.... I have no doubt your right, but how would `cat input.txt` as a placeholder be better than `(prog|script) <input.txt`? How does `cat input.txt | (prog|script)` allow `prog|script` to generate data in a different manner? Am I looking at the *"chicken - or - egg"* aspect of what you are saying wrong?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It allows you to show an example of the data. If he just wrote `prog | parallel -j5` then it wouldn't be clear what the output of `prog` is.

Comment: I see what you saying. That makes sense in that case.

Answer (score 2):

`cat input.txt | xargs -P5 -i bash -c "{}"` certainly works for most cases.

`xargs -P5 -i bash -c "{}" <input.txt` suggested by David below is probably better, and I'd imagine there are simple ways of avoiding the explicit `bash` usage as well.

Just to break this down a bit `xargs` breaks up input in ways you can specify.  In this case, the `-i` and `{}` tells it WHERE you want the broken up input and implicitly tells it to only use one piece of input for each command.  The `-P5` tells it to run up to 5 commands in parallel.

By most cases, I mean commands that don't rely on having variables passed to them or other complicating factors.

Of course, when running 5 commands at a time, command 5 can complete before command 1.  If the order matters, you can group commands together:

`echo 2;sleep 1`

(And the grouped sleep is also pretty useful for testing it to make sure it's behaving how you're expecting.)

Comment: Anything wrong with `xargs -P5 -i bash -c "{}" <input.txt`? to avoid the *UUOc*?

Comment: The order in which the 5 commands run is not an issue, just that the max limit is 5 at a time, or if there are less than 5 they will all run.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Definitely nothing that I'm aware of.  I UUOc fairly constantly and should probably learn to start avoiding it.